# HTML5 Audio player works on safari/Chrome, but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, audio

I've got an HTML5 audio player that works on Safari on the PC, but doesn't seem to work on (my) iPhone (4). Here's the code:

```
`    
function loadPlayer() {
    var audioPlayer = new Audio();
    audioPlayer.controls="controls";
    audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended',nextSong,false);
    audioPlayer.addEventListener('error',errorFallback,true);
    document.getElementById("player").appendChild(audioPlayer);
    nextSong();
}
function nextSong() {
    if(urls[next]!=undefined) {
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
            audioPlayer.src=urls[next];
            audioPlayer.load();
            audioPlayer.play();
            next++;
        } else {
            loadPlayer();
        }
    } else {
        alert('the end!');
    }
}
function errorFallback() {
        nextSong();
}
function playPause() {
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
        if (audioPlayer.paused) {
            audioPlayer.play();
        } else {
            audioPlayer.pause();
        }
    } else {
        loadPlayer();
    }
}

    function stop() {
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        audioPlayer.pause();
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    }


function pickSong(num) {
    next = num;
    nextSong();
}

var urls = new Array();
    urls[0] = '01_horses_mouth/mp3/01. Let The Dog See The Rabbit preface.mp3';
    urls[1] = '01_horses_mouth/mp3/02. The Other Horse\'s Tale.mp3';
    urls[2] = '01_horses_mouth/mp3/03. Caged Tango.mp3';
    urls[3] = '01_horses_mouth/mp3/04. Crumbs.mp3';
    urls[4] = '01_horses_mouth/mp3/05. Mood Elevator Reprise.mp3';
    urls[5] = '01_horses_mouth/mp3/06. Mood Elevator.mp3';
    urls[6] = '02_dub_project/mp3/01. Fearless Dub.mp3';
    urls[7] = '02_dub_project/mp3/02. Original Sound Dub.mp3';
    urls[8] = '02_dub_project/mp3/03. Rhok Shok Dub.mp3';
    urls[9] = '02_dub_project/mp3/04. Tron Dub.mp3';
    urls[10] = '02_dub_project/mp3/05. Eastern Fire Dub.mp3';
    urls[11] = '02_dub_project/mp3/06. Mary Jane Dub.mp3';

var next = 0;
`
```

Can anyone see anything obvious that would make this not work on iPhone?

There's also code for a canvas element, but I've hidden that on the iPhone version - the canvas at any rate. I commented out the code but that didn't seem to make a difference, so I'm guessing it's not a conflict. Here's the site:

http://lisadearaujo.com/clientaccess/wot-sound/indexiPad.html

Comment: Ah. I have figured this one out. On my desktop versions, I have hidden the player, as I was not using the default player element (I just needed the playlists and play/pause/stop buttons). This worked fine with the player in a hidden div. On the iPhone, however, the div has to display. 

I will either have to figure out how to restyle it to fit, or hide it some other way, but at least it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my browser versions, I have hidden the default audio player so I could use custom controls. This worked fine with the player in a hidden div. On the iPhone, however, the div has to display in order to function, even with custom controls (or so it appears).

I hid the div with a low z-index rather than with display:none.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 audio player on iPhone require the click of the user.

Work when you click on the player:

```
<audio src="foo.ogg" width="200px" height="200px" />
```